# FlutterWebviewPlugin listener doesn't recognize *.pdf as url

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a webview in Flutter and a webpage with a link to http://mywebsite.com/dummy.pdf

The problem is that the webview listener doesn't listen when the user clicks on the pdf link.

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) async {
      if (url.contains('.pdf')) {
        print(url); //This print is never done
      }
      if (url.contains('mailto:')) {
        print(url); //This print is ok
      }
      if (url.contains('txt')) {
        print(url); //This print is ok
      }
      if (url.contains('foobar')) {
        print(url); //This print is ok
      }
    }
```

How to solve this?

## UPDATE 1

This problem is related to those urls pointing to "unmanaged" files.

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) async {
      if (url.contains('.pdf')) {
        print(url); //This print is never done
      }
      if (url.contains('.doc')) {
        print(url); //This print is never done
      }
      if (url.contains('mailto:')) {
        print(url); //This print is ok
      }
      if (url.contains('.txt')) {
        print(url); //This print is ok
      }
      if (url.contains('.mp3')) {
        print(url); //This print is ok
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is a better approach or not, but if the issue is with PDF only, then we can sort this out via Dart programming method only.

However, I feel like you must do a check for this one too: `url.contains('pdf')`, rather than going for `.pdf` in the `contains()`

So, now the workaround is to do the following:

1. Check the length of the URL
2. Since the pdf would come at the last, so we need the last three items
3. Check if it is PDF only or not, like pdfString = Substring of the String of last three chars // In this way you  get the last three elements of the URL
4. Do a check whether pdfString == 'pdf', if yes, print('OK') else // do something

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
// This is a workaround for pdf only, so writing the code for that only
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) async {
   // technically this should give you the last three chars, which is pdf in this case
   var pdfString = url.substring(url.length-3); 

   // now checking if the pdfString contains that pdf or not
   if(pdfString == 'pdf'){
     //print your url
     print(url); // OUTPUT WILL BE http://mywebsite.com/dummy.pdf
   }
}
```

You should find this useful enough to be incorporated in the code. This is kind of a workable solution, **if the URL for PDF always ends with .pdf**.

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your reply! Actually the problem is that the listener ignores every url pointing to files that the webview cannot directly manage (.pdf, .doc, ...). The point here  is that I can download a PDF (or doc etc..) in other ways (not using the webview directly) but I need back the url from the listener (but at the moment the listener cannot give me back anything). I hope I've explained what's the problem! :)

Comment: however, not all pdf url will container .pdf